# What is to best way hot to create dynamic string template

Tags: javascript, regex, string, join

I would like to have a dynamic string template in Javascript like this:

```
let stringSentence = 'Hello, my name is --%-- and I am from --%--';
```

then ..

```
replaceString(stringSentence , ['John', 'London'];
```

Expected output: *Hello, my name is John and I am from London*

Another example:

```
let stringSentence = 'Hello, my name is --%-- and I am from --%-- and I drink a --%--';
replaceString(stringSentence , ['Jacob', 'New York', 'Juice'];
```

Expected output: *Hello, my name is John and I am from London and I drink a Juice*

My answer is, how is the best way how to implement it this string template system.

Can this be done without `for` loops or `split/join` array action? By regex? If so, how?

Comment: But why the `--%--` ? Why not use template literals? Or does the string come from another source?

Comment: @JonasWilms It is the only example, I can use everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replace, and replace every instance of `--%--` pattern with value from array

```js
let stringSentence = `Hello, my name is --%-- and I am from --%-- and I drink a --%--`

let arr =  ['Jacob', 'New York', 'Juice']

function replaceString(str,arr){
  let count = 0
  return str.replace(/--%--/g,()=> arr[count++] )
}

console.log(replaceString(stringSentence, arr))
```

Comment: I did prefer you version that used shift. But you got my vote :)

Comment: @Bibberty shift mutates original array, since the objects passed by functions are reference so you need to make a copy every time, else it will affect your original object, so i switched it to using just a counter instead of making copy of array every time

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Good call.

Answer (score 2):

Just a concise version of Code Maniacs version. ++ to Code Maniac.

```js
const stringSentence = `Hello, my name is --%-- and I am from --%-- and I drink a --%--`;

const arr =  ['Jacob', 'New York', 'Juice'];

const replaceString = (str,arr) => str.replace(/--%--/g,()=> arr.shift());

console.log(replaceString(stringSentence, arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array of words and use `replace()` `--%--` with the corresponding word.

```js
let stringSentence = 'Hello, my name is --%-- and I am from --%--';
function replaceString(str, arr){
  for(let elm of arr){
    str = str.replace('--%--', elm);
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(replaceString(stringSentence , ['John', 'London']))
```

Another way is to `split()` the given string by `--%--` and insert the words in the array and then `join()` it

```js
let stringSentence = 'Hello, my name is --%-- and I am from --%--';
function replaceString(str, arr){
  return str.split('--%--').map((x,i,a) => x + arr[i]).join('').slice(0, -9);
}
console.log(replaceString(stringSentence , ['John', 'London']))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually use a template literal like:

```
  const capitalize = str => str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);

  const welcome = ({ name = "Unknown", city }) => 
    `Hello, my name is ${name} and I am from ${capitalize(city)}`;

 console.log(welcome({ name: "Jonas", city: "stade" }));
```

With that you can easily determine what values are needed to build up the string, you can provide default values (e.g. the default name `"Unknown"`), and you can use one value at multiple positions, you can format the input (e.g. capitalizing the city), etc. etc. so that way is way more flexible & easier to use than the format proposed by you.

For sure that won't work if the string is not hardcoded but dynamically retrieved from another source. In that case I'd use a helper to build up a function like the above from a string:

```
  const template = str => obj => str.split("%").map((v, i) => i % 2 ? obj[v] : v).join("");

 const welcome =  template("Hello, my name is %name% and I am from %city%");

 welcome({ name: "Jonas", city: capitalize("stade") })
```